# How to plot the nodes from 0-2 and from 9 to 28, without including nodes from 2:9

Tags: plotting, matplotlib

I want to plot nodes from 0 to 28 without including nodes from 2:9
I tried to use this command, but got syntax error:

```
plt.scatter(node_coords[0:2&&10:28,0], node_coords[0:28,1], color='red', s=70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `&&` when slicing, but you can use `np.concatenate`. Here's an example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

node_coords = np.random.rand(28, 2)

selected_nodes = np.concatenate((node_coords[0:2], node_coords[10:28]))

plt.scatter(selected_nodes[:, 0], selected_nodes[:, 1], s=35)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think it would be better to not provide answers to low-effort and off-topic questions like this to promote good question etiquitte